# Splashscreen, threading and race conditions

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, mvvm

Not sure that was the best title.

I'm having some trouble with my Thread. In the `Application_Startup` I start a new thread that opens up a simple splash screen window with the help of a static helper class. In `Application_Startup` there's a method that checks whether the user has logged in or not and subsequently opens up a login window if he's not signed in already. At this point, if the login window appears, the splash screen should `close`, but it doesn't.

```
    private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(
        new ThreadStart(
            delegate ()
            { 
                SplashScreenHelper.SplashScreen = new Splash()
                // this works. the splash screen opens
                SplashScreenHelper.Show();
                System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
            }
        ));
        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        thread.IsBackground = true;
        thread.Start();

        check();
    }


    private void check()
    {  
        var clientid = (int) IPdevices.Properties.Settings.Default["clientid"];
        if (clientid > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                // this works
                SplashScreenHelper.ShowText("Looking for profile...");
            }
            catch (EntityException)
            {
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // This does not work
            SplashScreenHelper.Close();
            // this opens up fine.
            openLoginWindow();
        }
    }
```

Things begin to fail when we hit the `else` condition in the `check` method. To start, I put a break point in the `SplashScreenHelper.Close();` and found that the instance of `Splash` is null and therefore the `Close` coming from the `Splash` Window, never fires (see class below). But what's curious is that how can it be null if it was instantiated properly and the splash screen window displayed?

Here's the `SplashScreenHelper` class to get an idea:

```
class SplashScreenHelper
{
        public static Splash SplashScreen { get; set; }

        public static void Show()
        {
            if (SplashScreen != null)
            {
                SplashScreen.Show();
            }    
        }

        public static void Close()
        {
            if (SplashScreen == null) return;
            if (!SplashScreen.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
            {
                SplashScreen.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                    new Action(delegate()
                    {
                        System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.InvokeShutdown();
                        SplashScreen.Close();
                    }));
            }
            else
            {
                SplashScreen.Close();
            }
        }

        public static void ShowText(string text)
        {
            if (SplashScreen == null) return;

            if (!SplashScreen.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
            {
                SplashScreen.Dispatcher.Invoke(
                    DispatcherPriority.Normal,

                    new Action(delegate ()
                    {
((SplashScreenViewModel)SplashScreen.DataContext).SplashScreenText = text;
                    }
                ));
            }
            else
            {
                ((SplashScreenViewModel)SplashScreen.DataContext).SplashScreenText = text;
            }

        }
    }
```

When we hit that `else`, I have two windows: the splash screen window and the login window, though the splash window should have been closed but it doesn't because the splash screen instance is `null` and this is where I can't figure out what happens.

What I think is happening is that somehow the `check` method fires before the thread starts, opens the login window, hits the else statement, tries to close the splash screen but that splash screen thread never started and never instantiated it. *Then*, then thread finally instantiates the splash screen after all that.

Comment: Does your splash screen do anything?  If not, why not just use the built in mechanism and avoid the headache? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656886(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Well it displays information to the user at all times, module loading progress bars and it also includes a copyright notice and the publishone  version at the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure the first part of the code in your second thread runs before calling `check`.

[ManualResetEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent(v=vs.110).aspx)s are prefect for this!

```
using (ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(false))
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(
        delegate ()
        { 
            SplashScreenHelper.SplashScreen = new Splash()
            // this works. the splash screen opens
            SplashScreenHelper.Show();
            mre.Set(); // signal that we are done setting up the splash screen
            System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
        }
    ));
    thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    thread.IsBackground = true;
    thread.Start();

    mre.WaitOne(); // wait until the signal is received
}

check(); // now we can safely call check()
```

Comment: I'll give this a try